# Android Studio "Could not find installation home path"

Tags: android-studio, projector

I am getting the following error when trying to start Android Studio in a Linux env (using Projector). I have tried to reinstall AS multiple times, but the error persists. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
2022-03-08 09:04:39,045 [     20]  ERROR - oncurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor - Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory.
```

[image]
Thanks,
Markus

Comment: if you found a solution, please share it here too

Comment: Nope, no solution yet.